# Vue submit button from component does not submit

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component in Vue which I use a substitute for submit buttons. I can pass a handler to it, which the component calls after disabling itself and settings it status as loaded, and it can recover (enable itself again) after errors and display a nifty success animation if all goes well. This works well, with the code below:

```
// Submit.vue
<template>
    <button :type="type" :class="classes" :disabled="loading" @click="onClick">
        <span class="flag" v-if="flag"></span>
        <slot></slot>
    </button>
</template>

<script>
    import _ from 'lodash'
    export default {
        name: 'submit',
        props: {
            brand: {
                type: String,
                default: 'primary'
            },
            // If no handler is provided, will fallback to normal submit button
            handler: {
                type: Function,
                required: false
            },
            flag: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },
        data () {
            return {
                loading: false,
                success: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            type () {
                return typeof this.handler !== 'undefined' ? 'button' : 'submit'
            },
            classes () {
                return [
                    `btn btn-${this.brand}`,
                    this.loading && !this.success ? 'loading' : null,
                    this.success ? 'success' : null
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onClick (event) {
                if (this.success) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    return
                }
                this.loading = true
                if (typeof this.handler !== 'undefined') {
                    // Handler must return a Promise
                    this.handler.call()
                        .then(_.bind(() => {
                            this.onSuccess()
                        }, this))
                        .catch(() => {})
                        .then(_.bind(() => {
                            this.loading = false
                        }, this))
                }
            },
            resetSuccess () {
                this.success = false
            },
            onSuccess () {
                this.success = true
                setTimeout(this.resetSuccess, 2000)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

It falls back to a normal submit button if no handler is passed, assuming all you want is to auto-disable the button when the form is submitted. The only problem is **the form is not submitted** when I click the button created from the component.

I think it would be fairly easy to force the submission via JS with the `onClick` method, but I wanted to understand why it doesn't. Is it a browser issue? A security issue? A Vue issue? Or something else I'm missing that might be right in front of me?

Here's a JSFiddle for quick testing: https://jsfiddle.net/03fgwgy5/
The code is not exactly the same, as I'm using single-file components, but the gist is the same and the behaviour can be observed easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `loading` to false before you check for the existence of the `handler`. Since you bind the button's `disabled` attribute to `loading`, you are disabling the button and preventing the native click event from firing.

Just set the `loading` property after you've checked for the handler:

```
if (typeof this.handler !== 'undefined') {
  this.loading = true;
  ...
}
```

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/n7xb2ts6/)

Comment: One of these times it'll be right! Man I had one like that earlier this morning.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I had a feeling it was something obvious. The only problem is that I _do_ want the button to be disabled and have the `loading` class regardless of having a handler or not. I'll end up using JS to force submission, but you solved the riddle :)

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here's what I ended up doing:

```
onClick (event) {
    if (this.success) {
        event.preventDefault()
        return
    }
    this.loading = true
    if (typeof this.handler !== 'undefined') {
        // Handler must return a Promise
        this.handler.call()
            .then(_.bind(() => {
                this.onSuccess()
            }, this))
            .catch(() => {})
            .then(_.bind(() => {
                this.loading = false
            }, this))
    } else {
        this.$el.form.submit()
    }
}
```

This allows me disable the form on click and show the loading status, but still force submission.